# How to apply Canada's superficial loss rule for multiple sales?

Tags: canada, accounting, wash-sale, canada-revenue-agency

I know that a capital loss cant be claimed if you repurchase the asset within 30 days of the sell date.

```
   DATE     ACTION   SHARES   TICKER   CAP GAIN
1. Jan/01   BUY      1,000    MSFT     -
2. Jan/10   SELL     100      MSFT     ($500)

Need to wait until at least Jan/10 + 30D = Feb/10 to repurchase
```

But how exactly is the sell date calculated when there are multiple sales of the same security (at a loss).

```
   DATE     ACTION   SHARES   TICKER   CAP GAIN
1. Jan/01   BUY      1,000    MSFT     -
2. Jan/10   SELL     100      MSFT     ($500)
3. Jan/15   SELL     100      MSFT     ($500)

Need to wait until at least Feb/10? Feb/15? Something else?
```

What is the "proper way" to account for the bottom scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the U.S. wash sale replacement stock rule work?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48429/how-does-the-u-s-wash-sale-replacement-stock-rule-work)

Comment: The Canadian rule is the same as the US rule, so see the example in that answer.

Comment: @littleadv My question is regarding the specific date to use. I don't see an answer for that in your linked thread.

Comment: You'll need to wait until after Feb/15 for the replacement shares of the Jan/15 transaction, and until after Feb/10 for the replacement shares of the Jan/10 transaction. Not sure what confuses you.

Comment: @littleadv That was the answer I was looking for. Happy to accept it if you replied with an answer (and citation).

Comment: See the answer I linked to.